# Facebook Graph API returning 25 pages only, How to increase it's limit?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I getting data using:

```
get('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture,accounts', access_token);
```

But it is only returning 25 pages and returns a NEXT url to get the remainings. Is there any way I can put the **limit=100** attribute in the above code?

Comment: `/me?fields=…&limit=100` …?

Answer (score 1):

```
get('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture,accounts&limit=100', access_token);
```

Or, better use paging: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging